# mount -t cifs fails if password is not read from prompt, how to fix?

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I can successfully mount a windows network drive/share using this command:

```
mount -t cfis //servername/sharename /mnt -o 'username=user,sec=ntlmssp'
```

as running this commands prompts a password to be input and then if correct mounts.

According to [`man mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) I should be able to to this.

```
mount -t cfis //servername/sharename /mnt -o 'username=user,password=pwd,sec=ntlmssp'
```

or this

```
PASSWD='pwd' mount -t cfis //servername/sharename /mnt -o 'username=user,sec=ntlmssp'
```

However strangely both those commands fail with this message.

```
 mount error(13): Permission denied
```

Now because our company does this "supersmart" thing to require passwords with **special characters** mine does contain a exclamation mark "`!`". I know that this would have a special meaning to the command line shell, so I have escaped it properly such that if my password was `pwd!` I would issue those two commands:

```
PASSWD='pwd\!' mount -t cfis //servername/sharename /mnt -o 'username=user,sec=ntlmssp'

mount -t cfis //servername/sharename /mnt -o 'username=user,password=pwd\!,sec=ntlmssp'
```

but still it does not work.

Connecting to Windows I do not have any particular feeling of urgency to hide my password (of appearing in the bash history) so I would be happy to find a way to skip the password prompt.

Mostly I would like to know what the problem is?

Lastly I have even tried a credentials file which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a credential file

```
-o credentials=filename|cred=filename
specifies a file that contains a username and/or password and optionally the name of the  workgroup.
The format of the file is:

username=value
password=value
domain=value
```

Comment: The problem remains. 1) Even with credentials file it does not work. I only works if supplied via password prompt. Any idea?